# Restrict JSP/Servlet access to specific users only

Tags: jsp, servlets, security-constraint

I'm developing a web app. I'd like to be able to let some friends see it, but not others that stumble upon the url. I was going to put a landing page and then a simple password box. Once the correct password is entered, I'd just record it in the session and expose the site as usual for the rest of the time they keep the browser open.

Is there a standard way to do this? I'd be adding extra code to my webapp to support this, I'm not sure if there's a built-in way to do it already (I'm using java servlets).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [container managed authentication using deployment descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm). This requires no extra code in your side expect of a simple login form with an input and password field which submits to the URL `j_security_check`. Here's a basic example:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="j_username">
    <input type="password" name="j_password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Assuming that you've private pages in a folder named `/private` and the above login page is located in `/private/login.jsp`, then add the following entries to the webapp's `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Private</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>friends</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Private</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/private/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/private/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Then, in the servletcontainer which you're using you need to configure a so-called *Realm* for `Private`. Since it's unclear which servletcontainer you're using, here's a Tomcat 8.0 targeted document: [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html). You can configure it to verify the username/password combo against a XML file or a database or even a custom location.

---

A completely different alternative is to homegrow a login mechanism with help of a `Filter` which checks the presence of the logged-in user in the session scope. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795992/overriding-the-jsp-servlet-filter-jsp-to-wrap-in-an-authentication-model/1796428#1796428) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274279/filter-and-servlet-for-login/13276996#13276996) answer how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using simple authentication using htaccess

See http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Comment: That's Apache HTTPD specific. That will only work if he's using Apache HTTPD server as proxy in front of the JSP/Servlet container.